# Error: cannot access LifecycleObserver when I using pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer library

Tags: android, lifecycle

- 

*I'm using this library to manage the YouTube player*

**My code**

```
private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview_movie);
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.video_trailer_overview_movie_id);
        this.getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);  "<<-- The error is here (in LifeCycle can't be applied)"
    }
```

**Here my build.gradle of the app**

```
dependencies {
     def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"                                              "<--For lifecycle"
     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"   "<--For lifecycle"
     implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5' "<--For youtube"
}
```

**Here my XML of the app**

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
      android:id="@+id/video_trailer_overview_movie_id"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      app:videoId="S0Q4gqBUs7c"
      app:autoPlay="true"
      app:showFullScreenButton="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the import for the `YouTubePlayerView` is this
   import `com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView` and not the one used by google, which is why I got stuck for hours.
2. add this to gradle

   ```
    def lifecycle_version = '2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-  extensions:$lifecycle_version"
   ```